# implementation of exec() function in pipe named program

Tags: c, linux, pipe, exec

I have a trouble with exec() function.
My program should be called via terminal by typing something like "./a.out from to message" and print "from : to : message" as execution.
I have no idea, how to implement exec() function to allow me to type "./a.out from to message" and print something as result.
In the program I have to use named pipe in reading and writing "message".
How to solve it?

A piece of my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 int i = 0;
 char* fr0m[MAX], t0[MAX], message[MAX];

 execve("./a.out", "./a.out", "from.txt", fr0m, "t0.txt", t0, "message.txt", message, NULL);
 puts(strerror(errno));

 int File1 = mkfifo("opened.txt", 0666);
 int File2 = mkfifo("saved.txt", 0666);

 int Opened = open("opened.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0777);
 int Saved = open("saved.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDONLY | O_TRUNC, 0777);

 int File1Process = fork();

 int Scanner; 

 if( File1Process == 0 ) {

    char c;
    read( Opened, message, sizeof(message) );
    while( ( Scanner = read( Opened, &c, sizeof(message) ) ) > 0 )
            printf( "%i", message[i] );

    close( Opened );    
 }

 if( File1Process != 0 ) {
    write( Saved, message, sizeof(message) );
    close( Saved );

    printf("<");
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(fr0m); i++) printf( "%c", fr0m[i]);
    printf("> : "); 
}

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here.  The task, it seems to me, is to write a program that, when executed, takes three arguments, and which then echoes them back to the screen with a space-colon-space sequence separating the arguments in the output and a newline at the end.  The program will be run from a terminal window:

```
$ ./a.out source target 'what was said'
source : target : what was said
$
```

While you could write a second program to execute the one whose output is illustrated, there isn't a clear need for it.

In your code, you have:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 int i = 0;
 char* fr0m[MAX], t0[MAX], message[MAX];

 execve("./a.out", "./a.out", "from.txt", fr0m, "t0.txt", t0, "message.txt", message, NULL);
 puts(strerror(errno));
```

There are many problems in just this much of the fragment:

- If the `execve()` returns, it means it failed.
- You are calling `execve()` as if it was `execle()`.
- You are passing uninitialized pointers to `execve()`.
- You have arrays of `char *`, rather than arrays of `char`.
- Error messages are best reported on standard error, not standard output.

If the `execve()` fails, the program continues to create a pair of FIFOs, and then tries to open them.  The chances are that no other process has the FIFOs open, so the first open will block indefinitely.  Whatever else it does, the rest of the code seems completely extraneous to any reasonable interpretation of the task as stated in the question.

Your code should be very simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 4)
        printf("%s : %s : %s\n", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s from to 'message'\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The main defect in that is that it reports 'success' when it prints the usage error message, which is easily fixed.

If you want to a program to execute that program, then:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *envp[] =
    {
        "HOME=/home/user",
        "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin",
        "TZ=UTC0"
        0
    };
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s from to 'message'\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    argv[0] = "./a.out";
    printf("About to execute %s\n", argv[0]);
    execve(argv[0], argv, envp);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute %s\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}
```

Don't compile this code to `a.out`; you will end up with a program perpetually executing itself.  The `printf()` before the `execve()` lets you know that is happening; you'll have to interrupt it to stop it.